# Ionic 2 doesn't recognize es6 code on index.html and service worker

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2, service-worker

I updated `Ionic 2`, `codova` and the `app-scripts` to the latest versions and when I un-commented the `service worker block` in `index.html` file, I get this

> error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" on line 27 in
>   index.html file

and right after it, this

> error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of
>   null".

It seems to me that maybe `index.html` and `serice-worker.js` aren't transpiled (when I used `es5` code in `index.html` file, there wasn't an error in index.html file, but there was in `service-worker.js` file).

Comment: When you got this issue,in a webservice

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting this error due to arrow functions, if that is the case you can solve it by changing the service worker code in index.html with this

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
            .then(function ()  { console.log('service worker installed');})
            .catch(function(err) { console.error('Error', err);});
}
```